# Lock-free atomic bools on RISC-V in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, riscv

I have this C++ code that asserts atomic bools are always lock-free (for reference, this is from Godot Engine):

```cpp
static_assert(std::atomic_bool::is_always_lock_free);
```

This works fine on x86, but when compiling with GCC for RISC-V, this assert fails with this message:

```cpp
./core/templates/safe_refcount.h:140:34: error: static assertion failed
  140 |  static_assert(std::atomic_bool::is_always_lock_free);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This assert doesn't fail when compiling with Clang (clang++), it only happens with GCC (g++).

I've been looking around for awhile but the available resources for RISC-V are fairly low. I did find [this somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242067/stdatomicbool-lock-free-inconsistency-on-arm-raspberry-pi-3) about lock-free atomics on ARM on a Raspberry Pi 3 where the problem is that the compiler is unaware that atomic bools are guaranteed to be lock-free at compile time. If this is the case, perhaps I am just missing some compiler flag. Alternatively, it is possible that the target architecture is missing a RISC-V extension for this (I have tried both the default `rv64imafdc`, and `rv64gc`), but I doubt it since the same target works with Clang.

Comment: There is [an open issue](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc/issues/15) on github, so apparently this is just not implemented correctly in gcc.

Comment: Beware - RISC-V does not have sub-word atomics; atomic_bool can be implemented with a CAS loop at best (which is technically lock-free, but less efficient than a hardware solution).